# Error while getting object associated with selected rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, object, datagridview, get

I need to get the object associated to a row in a DataGridView.

So far I've done this with no success:

```
1)
 POI poi_seleccionado = new POI();
 poi_seleccionado = POI_grid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as POI;

2)  
POI poi_seleccionado = (POI)POI_grid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

I always get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: The code seems to be fine, what is `null` in your code?

Comment: Well, CurrentRow is Null so I'm wondering if I need to select one row by default when I load the form?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by adding this:

```
if (POI_grid.CurrentRow != null)
  {
       poi_seleccionado = POI_grid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as POI;
  }
```

It seems when the form is loaded, it doesn't selects a row by default..